# What license to choose when starting an open source project in a company?

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation

I'm interested in converting part of our company application into and open source project.

They will let me work on it (they need it) and publish it to their own GitHub account. I will be the only one working on it.
If I leave the company, I would like to continue contributing to it.

What kind of license should I choose to avoid the code being turned back into closed source and that would allow me to fork it without being troubled by the company ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid that any derivative is kept as closed-source, you will need a copyleft license. That ensures that any derivative work will need to be published with accompanying source as well. The established licensed in that area is the GPL.

If you only want to ensure that your current work remains free software, any open source license will do; the licenses are irrevocable. But MIT and BSD-style licenses allow - contrary to GPL - that derivatives can remain closed-source.

Comment: If I choose a GPL license, and then someone fork the project keeping the same license, there is no control possible over this person right ?

Comment: Yes, correct. That is true for any open source license. Anyone, anytime, for whatever purpose.

Comment: @Pat-rice, there might be some limited control through trademarks. With trademarks you can enforce that a fork uses a different name and branding, but that is about all the control you can get.

Comment: @Pat-rice, also, if your company is the sole copyright holder, they are not bound by any license terms and can decide to stop offering newer versions as open-source.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau but I thought that was the point of GPL license, that you must keep the GPL license if you modified a GPL licensed source code ?

Comment: @Pat-rice yes, you need to keep GPL (or a compatible copy-left license). But when the (modified) source code does not leave your computer (or your company - internal network), you can do what you want. But if that "what you want" is in contradiction to the license, you may not share the result with external 3rd-party in any way.

Comment: @planetmaker Ah ok, but that mean they would be dishonest about it, I think that's another matter :)

Comment: @Pat-rice no, that's not dis-honest. The license covers your rights when and where to use the software (everywhere and in any way), to share and modify the software and share modifications/derivatives (basically it's "use the same conditions under which you got it" - you are HERE bound by GPL limitations). Checking what you do on your machine requires spy-software; as such any limitations in that respect requires practically spy-software on your machine.

Comment: @planetmaker Ok I think I get what you're saying. What I meant is that if they do modifications, and then sell a service that is based on this GPL licensed source code, that would be a breach of GPL right ? (that's what I was thinking when I said dishonest)

Comment: Most likely it would NOT be a breach of the GPL. Running software on a server does not mean that you distribute the software and in turn you are not required to publish the software or reveal any modifications made to it - unless we are talking about the front-end HTML / java-script or similar which is actually distributed to a user of that web service. You might look for something like AGPL. That requires that servers make available the full source for services they offer.